# HTML Javascript CSS - div dis/appear causes borders to shift

Tags: javascript, html, css, border

I am new to HTML, Javascript, and/or CSS and I am trying to get a list to appear in an 'outer' box when a checkbox is checked in an 'inner' box.

The code for the jsfiddle is at:

https://jsfiddle.net/z6prq7a8/1/

and from there, one can see the .inner CSS code as:

```
.inner {
    width:800px;
    height:800px;
    margin-left:auto;
    border:1px solid #000;
    position:relative;
}
```

I have created two boxes, one inner, and one outer, and when I click on the checkbox in the 'inner' box, I want a list to appear in the 'outer' box. I believe I have the code correct, but when the list appears, the 'inner' box shifts downwards. How would I go about fixing this so that when I click the checkbox, the 'inner' box does not shift, and everything remains in the same place as when one loads the page?

Comment: `<ul>` is a block level element. If you don't want it to push the floating div down, you need to (old way) make it also float (new way) position the left and right parts side by side using flexbox, then make the <ul> appear inside the left part. In other words, a very quick fix is `#CPC { float: left; }` but doing it properly is better.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is in your CSS for the inner box. Since you don't want it to move when other elements are added, you want to use:

```
position: absolute;
```

However, we still want it to remain positioned inside the box correctly, so we add this CSS:

```
margin-left: 200px;
top: 0px;
```

Overall, all you need to change is your .inner to:

```
.inner {
    width:800px;
    height:800px;
    margin-left:200px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
```

The end result will look like this:

[image]

[image]